# How do you put quotes around the variable of a For loop in batch?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, windows-services

I am working on a batch script that will take a list of server, loop through them, find every service on each server that starts with a certain value, and query that service. However, given that service names can be created with spaces, I need to be able to put quotes around the for variable. What would be the best way to do this?

I've tried various methods of putting escape characters before and after the variable. I've also attempted setting the loop variable to a separate variable.

```
@ECHO off
ECHO Please list servers to query.
SET list=
SET /P list=Server Names:

FOR %%a IN (%list%) DO (
  FOR /F "Skip=1 Delims-" %%b IN ('wmic service where "name like 'ADOBE%%'" get Name ^| findstr /r /v "^$"') DO (
  ECHO %%b
  sc \\%%a query ^"%%b^"
  )
)
pause
GOTO :eof
```

The output show the service name of any service that starts with "ADOBE" on one of the servers entered in %list%.

What I'm getting is "EnumQueryServiceStatus:OpenService FAILED 1060:
The specified service does not exist as an installed service."

When I allow the script to echo, I see this:
HO AdobeARMservice
"    \[servername] query "AdobeARMservice

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is due to a spaces and carriage return characters in the output of `wmic`. If you add quotes around `%%b` in the line with `echo` in your code you'll see that the closing quote is missing from the output.

Working code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /F "Skip=1 Delims=" %%b IN ('wmic service where "name like 'ADOBE%%'" get Name ^| findstr /r /v "^$"') DO (
  for /f "delims=" %%c in ("%%b") do ( rem this will get rid of CR character
   set d=%%c
   :loop
   if "!d:~-1!"==" " ( rem here we'll remove the trailing spaces
      set d=!d:~0,-1!
      goto :loop
   )

   echo "%d%"
   sc query "%d%"
   )
)
```